# Hugo JS assets for single pages or sections

Tags: javascript, node-modules, hugo

The newer Hugo versions do offer advanced JS asset management, even handling resources from node_modules - But I don't get it.

I read the documentation and related news articles but i need a more tutorial like starting. Or an repository link where this is done like intended with the current Hugo version ( ~ 80+).

If a single page in your site requires a three.js sceene or another bigger JS import how are you doing this? where do you tell hugo to import the required libraries and how/where do you place the scripts where the library is used?

**This feels wrong to me:**

- include the assets for all pages
- just add the required cdn scripts in content/section/page.html and use it

**This is what I'm looking for:**

- import scripts just if needed
- use the provided mechanisms to include and bundle from node_modules
- a single js file for each task (setup threejs scene, initialising alpinejs, ...) somehow bound to the page or section where needed.
- a systematic approach that will work with Hugo modules

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you don't list what you have looked at.
However, I would start (and did start when implementing HUGO's assets/piping, etc. systems):

1. https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/
2. https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/js/
3. https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/js/#import-js-code-from-assets
4. https://www.regisphilibert.com/blog/2018/07/hugo-pipes-and-asset-processing-pipeline/
   In terms of ES build:
   import { hello } from 'my/module'; Is the example it gives in 3 above.
   Then to selectively use, 4 above gives an excellent example.
   Please let me know if that assists.

Comment: 4. is an awesome resource. I'm hones: I was ignoring resources that old. And with that clean description I might end up understanding the hugo docs much better ;-)

Comment: No worries Daniel. In true Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy fashion though, I do suggest you look into the question itself - their was possibly an assumption on the way Hugo is developed, I find the maintainers, particularly BEP, to be excellent and followed excellent design patterns, i.e. if it was built, their will be explicit and detailed pull requests, if it changes, the same will maintain, which are all public and able to be reviewed. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if you just want include or exclude static js for specific page like Page, Section, Home then you can add HUgo Page Variables to your Partial "footer.html" :

```
.IsHome
.IsPage
.IsSection
```

ex :

```
{{ .isHome }}
 <script src="home.js">
{{ end }}

{{ .isPage }}
 <script src="page.js">
{{ end }}
```

so you dont need to create multiple footer.html or insert manually.

more detail read Hugo Page Variable DOC here https://gohugo.io/variables/page/

Comment: That's fine, but is not utilizing assets/piping, etc. I.e. no JS management. https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/ for a primer. (note OP, though not clearly written, is referencing Assets Management in Hugo)

Comment: I'm looking for a "one source of truth" solution. In your example the head and the page needs to be aware of all the options